# choosing the fastest way of finding position

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this list `{1,7,8,10}` for instance. and a second list which is always smaller or equal to the first one say `{10,7}`. How can I find the position of the elements of the second list in the first list: the answer to above example is `{2,4}`. but I want the answer in this form: `{0,1,0,1}` which implicitly gives `{2,4}`.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node596.html). I don't claim that code can't be improved further, but it is reasonably fast.

Answer (score 5):

About twice as fast as any so far (actually over triple on larger lists, but see updates below), including coolwater's cool use of ordering. The sparse-array method is *fifty* times faster if lists (as in OP case) allow its use:

```
list1 = DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[{1,5000000}, 1000000]];
list2 = RandomSample[list1, 1000];

ClearSystemCache[]
resmetime = 
 First@Timing@(resme = 
     Replace[list1, Dispatch[Append[Thread[list2 -> 1], _ -> 0]], 1])

ClearSystemCache[]
ClearAll[f]
f[{_, _}] = 1; f[{_}] = 0;

rescoolwatertime = 
 First@Timing@(rescoolwater = 
     Map[f[#] &, 
       Split[Sort[
         Join[list1, Intersection[list1, list2]]]]][[Ordering[
        Ordering[list1]]]])


(* using SparseArray *)
ressatime = 
 First@Timing@(ressa = 
      SparseArray[(List /@ list2) -> 1, Max[list1]][[list1]] // 
       Normal;)

{resmetime, rescoolwatertime, ressatime, rescoolwatertime/resmetime, 
 rescoolwatertime/ressatime, resme == rescoolwater == ressa}

(* {2.870418, 9.547261, 0.202801, 3.32609, 47.077, True} *)
```

On smallish lists of positive integers (under a few thousand elements in the target and a "reasonable" subset in the searched list), bitmasks will probably beat all:

```
Reverse[Most@IntegerDigits[Fold[BitSet, 0, list2], 2, Max[list1] + 1]][[list1]]
```

Finally, a pretty snippet that has some advantages: within the constraints of lists not having duplicates and the search list being a subset of the target, it is agnostic as to contents (i.e., not limited to integers, could be symbols, strings, sublists, etc.- a trait shared by my first replacement-based solution) and is quite quick. (you *could* adapt the sparse/bitmap methods with mapping to do the same, but you'd likely kill their advantage in their respective areas with such machinations.):

```
Subtract[Tally[Join[list1, list2]][[All, 2]], 1]
```

Some quick timings on the netbook.

Larger lists, 5% search size, single run (I did not run bitmap over 200K - netbook...):

[image]

Smaller lists, 5% search size, 500 runs each (most were so fast single runs were below clock resolution):

[image]

Comment: Very nice, but replacing `(List /@ list2)` with `Transpose[{list2}]` decreases timing with 10% on my machine

Comment: @Coolwater: well, let me check that out...

Comment: @Coolwater: Added to times (sparse2) - seems a wash on my lounge-book, of course version/environment can make a difference. Clean though, I like it!

Answer (score 4):

```
list1 = {1, 7, 8, 10};
list2 = {10, 7};
Boole[MemberQ[list2, #] & /@ list1]
(*timing about 1,30*)
```

Edit, I found faster:

```
Module[{f}, SetAttributes[f, Listable];
(f[#] = 1) & /@ list2; f[_] = 0; f[list1]]
(*timing about 1,00*)
```

Edit, I found even faster (but list1 shouldn't contain duplicates):

Do initially: `f[{_,_}] = 1; f[{_}] = 0;`

```
Map[f[#] &, Split[Sort[Join[list1,
Intersection[list1, list2]]]]][[Ordering[Ordering[list1]]]]
(*timing about 0,45*)
```

Comment: thanks, no list1 does not have duplicates